# Puzzling implicit conversion during Array map()

Tags: java, arrays, scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have a use case where I am given a Java array of wrapper classes, wrapping an int, for instance, and I want to convert them a ValueSet of the same data, but I ran into a puzzling problem with implicit conversions.  Here is an example of the Java and Scala I am trying to do:

.../java/demoapi/SomeWrapper.java

```
package demoapi;

public class SomeWrapper {
    public static final int JavaOne = 1;
    public static final int JavaTwo = 2;
    public int m_theInt;
};
```

.../scala/demo.scala

```
package demotest

import demoapi._

object TestEnum extends Enumeration {
  val One, Two = Value
}

object SomeWrapperEx {
  implicit def fromJava(in: Array[SomeWrapper]): TestEnum.ValueSet = {
    in.map(x => fromInt(x.m_theInt))
  }
  def fromInt(in: Int): TestEnum.Value = {
    in match {
      case SomeWrapper.JavaOne => TestEnum.One
      case SomeWrapper.JavaTwo => TestEnum.Two
    }
  }
}
```

The map fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(11, 27) value m_theInt is not a member of demotest.TestEnum.Value
    in.map(x => fromInt(x.m_theInt))
                          ^
```

My question is: how did the type of an element of the Array get converted to a TestEnum.Value already?  I had to work around by dropping these sorts of implicits, but I feel like this should work somehow...

EDIT: I am sure there is more I need to do to get it to work, such as possibly converting the Array[TestEnum.Value] to a ValueSet, but I haven't gotten to that point yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting to convert your Array to a collection (ArrayOps) so you can operate on it.

But you're expecting to produce a ValueSet, and to do that, the machinery needs a way to build it, a CanBuildFrom.

That's provided implicitly here:

[See the docs for ValueSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration$ValueSet$).

Since you provide a way to convert your Array to a ValueSet, it will happily apply it in order to use the CanBuildFrom available to it.

`-Xprint:typer` shows you the direction it's taking:

```
implicit def fromJava(in: Array[demoapi.SomeWrapper]): demoapi.TestEnum.ValueSet = SomeWrapperEx.this.fromJava(in).map[Nothing, demoapi.TestEnum.ValueSet](((x: demoapi.TestEnum.Value) => SomeWrapperEx.this.fromInt(x.<m_theInt: error>)))(demoapi.this.TestEnum.ValueSet.canBuildFrom);
```

I have also run into problems working with ValueSet as a normal collection, so now I don't.

For example, always start with a ValueSet:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> object Days extends Enumeration { val M,T,W,Th,F,Sa,S = Value }
defined object Days

scala> val ds = (2 to 5).toArray
ds: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> Days.values filter (ds contains _.id)
res0: Days.ValueSet = Days.ValueSet(W, Th, F, Sa)
```

or construct by hand:

```
scala> Days.ValueSet.empty
res1: Days.ValueSet = Days.ValueSet()

scala> res1 + Days.T
res2: Days.ValueSet = Days.ValueSet(T)
```

which is all a CanBuildFrom does anyway:

```
scala> implicit val xxx = new collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[Int], Days.Value, Days.ValueSet] {
     | def apply() = Days.ValueSet.newBuilder
     | def apply(from: Array[Int]) = apply()
     | }
xxx: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[Int],Days.Value,Days.ValueSet] = $anon$1@6b474074

scala> (2 to 5) map (_ => Days.T)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Days.Value] = Vector(T, T, T, T)

scala> (2 to 5) map (Days(_))
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Days.Value] = Vector(W, Th, F, Sa)
```

Comment: So, its using the function that I am implementing in order to implicitly convert the array argument to that very same function?  That's very tricky.  

Ok, so followup: given I have a Java array of Java objects with an int member, what is the canonical way to convert that to a value set?  Should I provide only a method to convert a single object to a single Value, and then let the implicit CanBuildFrom stuff magically convert a container of X to a ValueSet of Value ?  Would that work?

Comment: @experquisite If you want to end with a valueset, start with a valueset. Otherwise, build it by hand.

Comment: Ok I feel dense, but I cannot start with a ValueSet, I must start with an Array[Wrapper] (because that is what the Java API I am working with gives me).  Each wrapper object wraps an integer, one of N up to about 40, and I want to convert that variable length array into a ValueSet.  At the moment, due to the above trickiness, I am doing it by hand with nothing implicit.

Comment: Ah I see, the filtering from the object is excellent, I will do that.  Thanks.